# env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements() in jni

Tags: java-native-interface

i got problem in releasedoublearrayelements its crashing in this function so could you please help me out of this
this is my code:

```
jdouble *dxyz = new jdouble[3];
    dxyz[0] = 0.0;
    dxyz[1] = 0.0;
    dxyz[2] = 0.0;
    jdoubleArray darr = env->NewDoubleArray(3);
    env->SetDoubleArrayRegion(darr,0,3,dxyz); 

    jclass dclass = env->GetObjectClass( darr );
    jobjectArray iarr = env->NewObjectArray(nbControlNodes,dclass,darr);
    env->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(darr,dxyz,JNI_ABORT);//its crashing here
```

Answer (score 0):

`ReleaseDoubleArrayElements` is meant to be used for primitive arrays (yours `dxyz`) obtained via `GetDoubleArrayElements`. That way, JNI creates a C-array for you, and it needs to know when to dellocate. The crash most probably occurs because `Release` is trying to deallocate your `dxyz` with `free()`. You have created `dxyz` with `operator new` and you are expected to free it with `delete`.